# Add and resize UIImageView to UIView which covers it exactly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uiimageview

I have a UIView with a size, and a UIImageView with a different intrinsic size. The UIImageView stretches its content with UIViewContentModeScaleToFill.

I would like to add the UIImageView as a subView to UIView, so that the UIImageView covers the UIView *exactly*.

This was my first attempt, the UIImageView is scaled as it should be, but unfortunately it is off position, and I don't understand why. Self is the UIView.

```
self.imageView.bounds = self.bounds;
[self addSubview:self.imageView];
```

Edit:

I used this one:

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);
```

I come from Cocos2d, and when you add a subview to a view you always *have* to use contentSize there (similar to bounds in UIKit), using frame is forbidden, because the original view might have been rescaled or rotated already. I really don't understand why using bounds is not correct in this case, and why it is off position, and how come frame is the correct one to use.

Edit2:

I did some tests where I rotated and scaled the UIView before I added the UIImageView to it. If the UIView is scaled or rotated, then using frame doesn't correctly place the UIImageView. I still don't think using frame in this case is a *proper* solution, because I can't be sure UIView hasn't been scaled or rotated before.

Edit3:

This one works perfectly, even if UIView has been scaled or rotated before:

```
self.imageView.frame = self.bounds;
```

Comment: should it be ``self.imageView.frame= self.frame`` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `setFrame:` as opposed to changing the bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Bounds and frame are not the same thing, which frame indicate the position of a view.

Therefore, you shouldn't set bounds of imageView, try to set its frame instead.

```
self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, self.bounds.size.height);
[self addSubview:self.imageView];
```

That should work!

Edit:

In UIKit, a view is visible when its position and bounds have been set. In other words, you have to set its frame instead of bounds. That's different from Cocos-2D.